# Adding 2x16GB RAM to existing 2x8GB in a workstation

Tags: memory, motherboard

If I have a workstation (Dell Precision 3620) with 4 memory slots and 2 of them are occupied with a 8GB module each, can I add two 16GB modules in the two empty slots, for a total of 48GB?
Or all 4 slots must address the same amount of memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All 4 slots do not have to have the same size RAM.  It is usually best to add in matched pairs, which you are doing anyway.  (Some motherboards have features like dual channel that may not work if the pairs aren't exactly the same, but this may not aways be the case.)  More important is to make sure that your motherboard supports the size and speed of RAM that you want to install.  In your case, [it appears that your workstation can handle up to 64GB](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Dell/precision-workstation-3620#memoryResults), so adding this additional 32GB should not pose a problem.  Keep in mind also that RAM speeds and timings always perform at the lowest common setting, so it's best to match what you already have when possible.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can put a couple of 16GB modules on the other couple of empty memory slots as long as they are same size in couples.

Comment: sorry mispelled 16 to 8Gb

Comment: Are you able to support this answer with any sort of [documentation](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_dell_precision_workstation/precision-t3620-workstation_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf)?

Answer (score -2):

It mostly depends on the motherboard and CPu as far as I know. Most motherboards can handle different modules in different channels, but I'm not so sure about different modules in the same channels.

Also, pay attention to the clock speed and timings, as the slowest sticks will throttle the faster ones.

My rule of thumb is to use the same modules in a single channel, same voltage in all slots, and clock/timings as close as possible.

Comment: So are you saying the author's motherboard does support the described configuration or are you saying it is not supported?  If you say it is supported you should backup your statement with information from the manual at the very least.