# 2 x 8gb RAM with 2 x 16 GB ram

Tags: memory, motherboard, speed, ramdisk, memory-card

The computer came with 2 x 8GB.  That works well like that. I Recently upgraded my PC:

- I replaced the RAM, so now, I have 2 x 16GB ram on the motherboard (Asus ROG Strix B550-E) spaced apart from each other (IE) one slot empty before and between them. All of the RAM cards are 3600 MHz DDR4 RAM cards made by the same company that made the RAM the computer cam with.
- So there are two empty slots.

I added the remaining 2 8GB sticks back to the mother board - with 2 x 16GB? (total of 48 GB RAM). But, they seem to have overheated and kept on getting blue screen of death.

What went wrong? i.e. Was the 16-8-16-8 configuration wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You have provided zero information about your hardware, if it does or doesn't support 48 GB DDR4, cannot be determined by the information in your question.  If you have four DDR4 slots the best way to determine if it does or doesn't support 48 GB is to use all four slots.  Check your manual for your system's optimized memory configuration.

Comment: thanks appreciate that, it is an Asus ROG Strix B550-E

Comment: If your memory is paired you'll need to follow the instructions in the mainboard document to pair the memory correctly. If the memory is not paired it won't matter. Based on your description that the system is freezing and heating, you may have a bad mainboard or dead/dying RAM stick.

Comment: Partially related: https://superuser.com/questions/1267322/is-it-bad-to-have-mismatched-ram-sizes-16-16-8-8 Not related: https://superuser.com/questions/1254478/adding-2x16gb-ram-to-existing-2x8gb-in-a-workstation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_geometry

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [motherboard manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/ROG_STRIX_B550-E_GAMING/E16546_ROG_STRIX_B550-E_GAMING_UM_WEB.pdf), and the Asus ROG Strix B550-E motherboard should support up to 128 GB of RAM. If you do indeed put 4 sticks of memory, they should be alternating so that the matching sticks end up running in dual-channel mode. Check if you have a BIOS update or if your BIOS settings are causing instability with regard to the memory configuration, because it *should* run fine.